# Get data from ignite cache using Cassandra querying

Tags: c++, cassandra, ignite

I have a Cassandra database table which is cached to ignite cache. I want to use some select query to this table. Is it possible to achieve this using SqlFieldsQuery & QueryFieldsCursor in c++ ? or is there any other option for doing this?
I just done a try using this

```
SqlFieldsQuery sql ("select * from user_permission");
QueryFieldsCursor cursor = cache.Query(qry);
while (cursor.HasNext())
    {
        QueryFieldsRow row = cursor.GetNext();
        std::cout << row.GetNext<std::string>() << row.GetNext<std::string>() << std::endl;
    }
```

But got an error like this " Failed to parse query: select * from user_permission"

Comment: Can you provide full stack-trace from the log file? That would help to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't query Cassandra using query API, you query data that is already in Ignite. So prior to executing queries, you have to preload data from Cassandra to Ignite. For this you need to configure Cassandra persistence store [1] and then use `cache.LoadCache` method.

Second of all, you need to make sure that SQL is configured properly as well [2].

[1] https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra

[2] https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: After i calling the `cache.LoadCache` Cassandra is loaded to ignite cache right?  So is it possible to use SQL query to get the  data from cache. I want to use some `SELECT` query from the cache

Comment: Yes, after data is loaded, you can execute SQL queries. See link [2] in the response.

Comment: In my Cassandra table i have 3 columns `id(Primary Key), desc, group`. i am putting  the data using ignite `id` set as `Key` and other 2 are `values`. When i execute `SELECT * FROM user_permission` its works But i got only the `value` fields and `key` value is missing. Also i just try `select * from user_permission where id=1` this query always fails.

Comment: What is the exception it fails with? Most likely configuration is incorrect and `I'd column is not defined.

Comment: its shows an error like `what():  Failed to parse query: select * from user_permission where id=1`    Persistamce file looking like `<persistence keyspace="sam" table="user_permission">
<keyPersistence class="com.test.user_permission" strategy="POJO">
    <partitionKey>
        <field name="id" column="id" />
    </partitionKey>
</keyPersistence>
<valuePersistence class="com.test.user_permission" strategy="POJO">
    <field name="desc" />
    <field name="groupid" />
</valuePersistence>
</persistence>`

Comment: Also my `queryEntities` <property name="queryEntities">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
            <property name="keyType" value="user_permission"/>
            <property name="valueType" value="user_permission"/>
            <property name="fields">
                <map>
                    <entry key="desc" value="java.lang.String"/>
                    <entry key="groupid" value="java.lang.String"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>

Comment: I don't see `id` field in query entities. I guess that's the reason.

Comment: How can i add `id` entity? I just give a try like `<entry key="groupid" value="java.lang.String"/>` its added just above the line of <entry key="desc" value="java.lang.String"/> but its also fails

Comment: Well, `groupId` is not the same as `id` :) If you use `id` from database directly as a key, without wrapping it into a POJO, you can use `_key` name to query it.